# What is the best way to find string containing a sequence of identical digits in SQL? (fake phones search)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-like

The first thing what comes into mind is use a bunch of `LIKE` conditions delimited by `OR` (as shown below).

```
(p.string like '%1111111%'
or p.string like '%2222222%'
or p.string like '%3333333%'
or p.string like '%4444444%'
...)
```

Possible results:

```
Phone
----------
761111111
3718888888
+214444444
```

But maybe someone can suggest another - more elegant - way to do this?

P.S.

`Full-text-search` is not an option in my case.

Comment: Do you want to find strings which contains only one recurring character or strings containing recurring characters besides some other characters?

Comment: @CrimsonKing second option - actually question about finding fake phone numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** To find recurring numbers, you can use a function like this. It returns 1 if any of the characters in @text are used at least @min times consecutively.

```
create function IsRecurring(@text varchar(255), @min int) returns int as
begin
    declare @i int = len(@text) - @min + 1
    declare @result int = 0
    while @i > 0 begin
        if replace(substring(@text, @i, @min), substring(@text, @i, 1), '') = '' begin
            select @result = 1
            break
        end
        select @i = @i - 1
    end
    return @result
end
```

Example usage:

```
select dbo.IsRecurring('84455552', 4)
```

Returns 1 if any of the characters are used at least 4 times consecutively.

Comment: Before using this function on real (big) data it would be useful to rewrite it using set-based approach (probably recursive `CTE`) - to avoid the use of low-performance `while` loop. But even in this case, the solution is not elegant. (anyway +1 for taking the time)

Comment: Well, this is a generic solution to find ANY recurring character which recurs a GIVEN number of times, it's not optimized for your special need. In your case (finding fake phone numbers), I would create a table containing 10 values ('11111','22222' and so on) and use JOIN and LIKE together. It should be quite fast, with an easy-to-read WHERE clause.

Comment: I thought to create a table with all possible combinations of seven-digits-length-sequences inside the ten-digit string and `JOIN` it by exact match... This should be quite an efficient solution, but really inflexible and clumsy

Comment: If you are using .NET, you may consider creating an SQL-CLI stored function for string operations. I had done it for the Levenshtein algorithm and it was literally several hundreds times faster than the equivalent T-SQL code.

Comment: funny but I already have such procedure (C#, SQL-CLR), but I use for finding similar addresses :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below:

```
select field_name 
from table_name 
where  CONTAINS(field_name, '"1111111*" OR "2222222*" OR "3333333*"')
```

Make sure you have full-text search feature installed when you use this.

Reference [here](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3446891/Understanding-SQL-Server-Full-Text-Indexing.htm).

Comment: Please review the edit I made to your post. In summary, don't abbreviate words: "You" not "U". Please start sentences with capital letters. Finally, if you have long lines of code, wrap them on to new lines so you don't have to scroll horizontally to read the code.

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for your valid comment

Comment: No problem, you could probably further improve your answer with some explanation as to what this will achieve and how it will solve the problem.

Comment: @ArunPrasanth thanks but `Full-text-search` is not an option in my case - I can't create an index on source table

Comment: @Andrey ok then can u go for regular expressions ?

Comment: as I know Sql Server does not support regular expressions... it maybe possible only through integration with `SQLCLR` but it is not an option too